# show specific user page in Telegram

Tags: cordova, telegram

I'm creating an app by `phonegap` and I want to open Telegram groups or channels from my app.

In other mean when I click on a group , Telegram open and that group shows to user.

I used the following code but I don't know how to switch to specific 
@username page :

```
   var username = 'http://telegram.me/telegram';
    navigator.startApp.start("org.telegram.messenger", function(message) {  /* success */
        console.log(message); // => OK
    },
    function(error) { /* error */
        console.log(error);
    });
```

I've tried to do this by open `tg:resolve?domain=username` in browser but my browser give me an erro :

`net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple.
Telegram Links follow the sheme: https://t.me/

So if the group is a public supergroup and has a public username (e.g. @newchat) you can reference it by this link (e.g. t.me/newschat)